# Checking if command process is actually running

Tags: macos, terminal

I want to know if a process is actually running (ie, doing something) and not stuck somewhere.

In my case, I am installing `clang-8.0` using `macports`. It has been a while (like an hour) since it showed `---> Building clang-8.0` on the terminal window. I am unsure if it actually is doing anything or has gotten stuck (if the latter case, I will `Ctrl-C` out of it). As you might have guessed, I do not see the standard input prompt on the terminal window.

Answer (score 1):

You might try to install htop which shows processes that are running ( more user friendly version of top command)

And also I think brew is more versatile than macports for installing packages (or programs) .

Comment: So, open another terminal to run ```htop`` or ```top``?

Comment: Yes, just open another tab .

Comment: on my machine, the top of the window or tab shows what process is running so you can tell if the window or tab is doing anything.